# Cron in bash (linux)

Tags: linux, bash, cron, backup

I need to add this script to cron. For example, make a backup every week. But I don't know how to pass values. The script doesn`t have any arguments, bat values read from the console.   Can you help me, please?

````
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Write what you want or -h to know how script works:  " command
if [ $command = "backup" ]
then
    IFS="~"
    read -p "Write  extensions of file to backup:   " exts
...
    ```
````

Comment: Re-write the script to accept arguments rather than trying to shoehorn prompts into cron ...

Comment: [This](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/bash-interactive-prompts) site recommends using standard input and the `yes` command.

Comment: Use the `expect` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a driver script that provides input to the script via a here-document.

```
#!/bin/bash

/path/to/backup_script <<EOF
backup
ext1~ext2~ext3
EOF
```

Then put this driver script in `crontab`.